# Resize TabPane on runtime (JavaFX8)

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a window that looks like this:

[image]

What I want, is when user selects specific item from `combobox` at the bottom, additional `labels` and `textfields` appears between `buttons` and bottom `textfield`, so it will look something like this:

[image]

For this I'm using an additional grid pane with height=0:

[image]

And when I simply add rows to that grid from builder, tabPane is being resized automatically and I get what I need as it shown on second picture. But when I'm trying to do it in code, like this:

```
            ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
            ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
            ColumnConstraints col3 = new ColumnConstraints();
            ColumnConstraints col4 = new ColumnConstraints();
            ColumnConstraints col5 = new ColumnConstraints();
            ColumnConstraints col6 = new ColumnConstraints();

            myGrid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6);

            myGrid.add(new Label("Label"), 0, 0);
            myGrid.add(new Label("Label"), 0, 1);
            myGrid.add(new Label("Label"), 0, 2);
            myGrid.add(new Label("Label"), 0, 3);
            myGrid.add(new Label("Label"), 0, 4);
            myGrid.add(new Label("Label"), 0, 5);

            myGrid.add(new TextField(), 1, 0);
            myGrid.add(new TextField(), 1, 1);
            myGrid.add(new TextField(), 1, 2);
            myGrid.add(new TextField(), 1, 3);
            myGrid.add(new TextField(), 1, 4);
            myGrid.add(new TextField(), 1, 5);
```

- In here `myGrid` - is that `gridpane` with height=0 at the begginin. And I'm having such screen, with `tabpane` not re-sized:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Could someone explain please?

**BTW** - on all other elements like HBox and other everywhere `pref Height = USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`

Comment: I still don't get your question. Does your `GridPane` doesn't expand with the `TabPane` or do you want a `ScrollPane` when there are more children to show in it than the available size?

Comment: No, I don't need a `ScrollPane`, I need a `TabPane` to increase size when new items (`Labels` and `TextFields` here) are being added to `GridPane`, so all items would be seen on window(not like on the last screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

I believe calling `myGrid.autosize();` after adding all children should solve your problem.

Comment: So far I have tried dynamically set prefHeight of TabPane. And I think that problem is definitely in TabPane, because myGrid actually being resized, but it's not seen because TabPane don't grow. Thank for reply, but autosize() also didn't work, even I've tried it on TabPane and myGrid.

Comment: Instead of setting the tabPane's height to 700, you could try setting it to myGrid.height + 100 (or try another value instead of 100. It should be a bit larger than myGrid though.)

Comment: Ok, that seems to be better than setting 700, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me as a solution ("dirty" solution) worked this:

```
// Height set manually
tabPane.getScene().getWindow().setHeight(700);
```

If someone knows how to set it's height dynamically (depending on GridPane height), please, respond.